# NPM - typescript needs updating to 2.4.1 from 2.2.2 but we can't, as it's a symlink

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I got the following error when trying to install typescript via NPM. What is the problem?

Command:

```
npm install typescript
```

Error:

```
typescript needs updating to 2.4.1 from 2.2.2 but we can't, as it's a symlink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously ran `npm link typescript`. Ran `npm update typescript -g` and then everything worked.